# Need advise for php code

Tags: php

I just wrote this code for my own dictionary that I'm creating at this moment:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="style-dictionary-list"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="col-sm-12">
      <?php
        if($language == '' || $language == 'Английски')
         {
           $alphas = range('a', 'z');
         }
         else if($language == 'Български')
         {
           $alphaText = 'а б в г д е ж з и й к л м н о п р с т у ф х ц ч ш щ ъ ь ю я';
           $alphas = explode(" ",$alphaText);
         }
         else if($language == 'Гръцки')
         {
           $alphaText = 'α β γ δ ε ζ η θ ι κ λ μ ν ξ ο π ρ σ ς τ υ φ χ ψ ω';
           $alphas = explode(" ",$alphaText);
         }
         else if($language == 'Нидерландски')
         {
           $alphaText = 'a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y ij z';
           $alphas = explode(" ",$alphaText);
         }
         else if($language == 'Латински')
         {
           $alphaText = 'a b c d e f g h i k l m n o p q r s t v x y z';
           $alphas = explode(" ",$alphaText);
         }
         else if($language == 'Старобългарски')
         {
           $alphaText = 'а б в г д е ж ꙃ ꙁ і ї ꙇ и ћ к л м н о п р с т ѹ ф х ѡ ш ц ч щ ъ ꙑ ы ь ѣ ю ꙗ ѥ ꙙ ѫ ѩ ѭ ѯ ѱ ѳ ѵ';
           $alphas = explode(" ",$alphaText);
         }
         else if($language == 'Старогръцки')
         {
         $alphaText = 'α β γ δ ε ϝ ζ η θ ι κ λ μ ν ξ ο π ϻ ϙ ρ σ ς τ υ φ χ ψ ω';
         $alphas = explode(" ",$alphaText);
         }
           
         foreach($alphas as $k => $v)
         {
     ?>
     <a class="word_heading <?php if($language == 'Старобългарски') { echo 'bulgarian_font'; } ?>" href="dictionary.php?alpha=<?php echo $v; ?>"><?php echo $v; ?></a>
     <?php
        }
     ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

which gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UueSc.png) table, with the words list on it and above it's the alphabet of that particular language. Now when I try to select a random letter I'm redirected back to the dictionary.php page. It is becouse of this code I think:

```html
<a class="word_heading <?php if($language == 'Старобългарски') { echo 'bulgarian_font'; } ?>" href="dictionary.php?alpha=<?php echo $v; ?>"><?php echo $v; ?></a>
```

which has this "href="dictionary.php?alpha=">" inside. Is there any posibility to tell this code to redirect me to the selected letter by language and not to send me back to the front page? I tried some codes, but it didn't work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: add `$language` to that link: `href="dictionary.php?alpha=<?php echo $v; ?>&language=<?php echo $language; ?>"`

Comment: Jeff, i had used only `&language` next to the the `href="dictionary.php?alpha=<?php echo $v; ?>`, but now with the `=<?php echo $language; ?>` works great. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basicly want to preserve a current selection in future links. So all you need to do is to include that param to that link:

```
href="dictionary.php?alpha=<?php echo $v; ?>&language=<?php echo $language; ?>"
```

Another possibility would be the use of `SESSION` vars.

Comment: I jsut did that. It's working. But will this also work for, lets say a translation table [link](http://imgur.com/a/snv7u) by which I had used this code `<span class="<?php if($v['word_language'] == 'Старобългарски') { echo 'bulgarian_font'; } ?>"><a style="color: gray;" href="javascript: showWord"><?php echo $v['word_meaning']; ?></a></span>`, but when I click the translation I'm not redirected to the word of that language. Any advise for that? Thank you kindly!

Comment: I don't see the js function `showWorkd()`, but you a defenitely missing the brackets there and you'd need to add a param to that function, right?

Comment: please make a new question for that new problem. Also please don't post that much code into comments.

Comment: Okey. Thanks for you help on this one. Need to wait another 4 days for that.

Answer (score 0):

That logic should be done either in a **Model** or a **Library**. You should never do any logic in your views, also if you have those conditions in a model or a library you can re-use them in another view.

I don't know what framework you are using or if you are using one, but you should consider using an **MVC** pattern.

> Explanation: https://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/

If you decide to use an MVC framework you can create a Model for the Language and then take care of the language logic in that specific model.

> Some useful frameworks:
>   http://mashable.com/2014/04/04/php-frameworks-build-applications/#pyxpYzV9qaqN

Comment: I know where you're going, but unfortunately I'm not an php expert to do such things. Maybe in the future. But hey thank you for ur advise.